# C++ get error after trying to check if pointer is null

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program using single linked list. I'm adding element from the end of linked list, and to do that i need to do null check. But after i try to check if element is NULL or nullptr, i get error. Is problem in `!*head` check method? P.S Also would like to hear if there is better way to create/insert new node in the linked list.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct vertex vertex;
typedef struct edge edge;

typedef struct vertex {
    int vertex;
    struct vertex * next;

    edge ** head;

}vertex;

typedef struct edge {
    int vertex1, vertex2;
    struct edge * next;
}edge;

void add_vertex(vertex ** head, int vertex_value) {

    vertex * new_vertex = new(vertex);
    new_vertex->vertex = vertex_value;

    if (!*head) {
        new_vertex->next = NULL;
        *head  = new_vertex;
        return;
    }
    vertex * tracer = *head;

    while (tracer->next != NULL) {
        tracer = tracer->next;
    }
    tracer->next = new_vertex;
    new_vertex->next = NULL;

}
int main() {
    vertex ** head = nullptr;
    add_vertex(head, 1);
}
```

I get read access violation error in add_vertex functions on `if(!*head)` moment.

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers in c++ at all?

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need `typedef struct`.  With `struct vertex`, `vertex` is a type.  You may want to either stay in C language or review a good book on C++.

Comment: Since you are using C++, you may as well make your life simpler and use `std::list` or `std::vector` rather than creating your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to dereference `head` which is it self NULL.
That is illegal in C++.

The way your `add_vertex` function is built, you must never send it NULL parameter as `head`.
Allocate a `head` in `main` and that problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In main

```
vertex *head = nullptr;
add_vertex(&head, 1);
```

This fixes your problem, but it would be better to pass head by reference.